water pressure tank troubleshooting and low water flow
I noticed my well pump was cycling on/off more than it should.  I turned off power to the well pump and drained the water from the system to test the air pressure charge in the pressure tank.  It had no pressure so I pumped it up to 38psi (2 psi below the pump cut in pressure).   After turning the well back on I have a new issue.  When I run some water through a faucet it starts out with good pressure/flow but slowly reduces to almost no pressure/flow.  I thought maybe I forgot to open a shut off valve but everything is open.  To further troubleshoot, I let the air charge out of the pressure tank and now I have water pressure/flow again, but pump is cycling on/off too much, as you would expect.  It seems when the pressure tank has the correct air pressure charge, my water supply looses pressure/flow upstream of my water softener system.  Is a failed pressure tank somehow causing this or is my water softener system closing off for some reason related to the pressure tank?

Did you in fact valve off the water line coming from the well before you drained the tank? If so, is this a 90 degree ball valve or a multi-turn valve? If it's not a ball valve, it's possible that the valve broke internally in a barely-open state.
